# How can I redirect java program output to another program?

Tags: java

I want to write my own desktop keyboard, that can be used to work with some programs like excel. I've already written all graphical stuff, but i can't find any information about redirecting program output to another program. I found Apache POI, but it can be used only to work with Microsoft documents. Is there, for example a buffer, where can I send my letters or chars in ASCII? And next to be shown in my document or note?

Comment: I believe this task is not allowed in Java because of the security.

Comment: Do you mean you'd like to make software keyboard with GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there, for example a buffer, where can I send my letters or chars in ASCII?

Yes. It's called the [`Clipboard`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Clipboard.html). You can call [`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getDefaultToolkit%28%29) and then use [`Toolkit.getSystemClipboard()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getSystemClipboard%28%29) to get it.

```
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
clipboard.setContents("Some ASCII Text", this);
```

Note that this is the same buffer used for copy (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>) and paste (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>) (or their platform specific counterparts).